# Django 1.8: Function not called on Signal

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, django-signals

I'm picking up on a code which should send a signal every time a user logs in. Thats not happening though. The function get_create_stripe() isnt getting called when the user logs in. 
Anyone can tell whats wrong?
I'm working in Django 1.8 and the whole code is [here](https://github.com/ShubhamRathi/Django-ecommerce/blob/master/accounts/signals.py).

Gist about the code: This code is part of an e-commerce site which users stripe as its payment gateway. Intent is, every time user logs in, we create a new stripe id or return an existing one.

Is it because this function is not in models.py? This is written to a file 'signals.py' and I'm not quite sure how Django should understand to call get_create_stripe() from a signal call in this file. Is it so?

```
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from .models import UserStripe

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


def get_create_stripe(sender, user, *args, **kwargs):
    new_user_stripe, created = UserStripe.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    print "hello"
    if created:
        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email = str(user.email)
        )
        print customer
        new_user_stripe.stripe_id = customer.id
        new_user_stripe.save()

user_logged_in(get_create_stripe)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect your signal method to the signal.

Something like

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

@receiver(user_logged_in, sender=UserStripe)
def get_create_stripe(sender, user, *args, **kwargs):
```

EDIT: Also, what is this:
    user_logged_in(get_create_stripe)

That is not how signals work. Either you do what I wrote above, or do this:

```
user_logged_in.connect(get_create_stripe)
```

Comment: I did the latter but its still not working. What else could I try?

Comment: How is your user getting logged in?

Comment: I'm logging in and out through the superuser in admin. I just have one user, which is the admin.

Comment: Did you import your `signals.py` file in `__init__.py` of the module it is in? Because the code that isn't loaded, would not execute.

Comment: @user248884 please select answer as chosen answer, if your problem was solved.

Comment: @user248884 don't edit other answers, write your own.